# Creating a +1 and -1 button

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I want a button that will increase my record data by 1 or decrease by 1.

- Table is: `Sellables`
- Field is: `QtyOnHand`
- Form text is: `txtQOH`

This is my attempt:

```
Private Sub cmdQOHAdd_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdQOHAdd_Click

    Dim x As Integer
    x = Me.txtQOH.Value + 1 = Me.txtQOH.Value
    Refresh

Exit_cmdQOHAdd_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdQOHAdd_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdQOHAdd_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the field `QtyOnHand` is bound to the textbox `txtQOH` (i.e. that `QtyOnHand` is the **Control Source** of the control `txtQOH`) and assuming that your Form permits edits, then the following should suffice:

```
Private Sub cmdQOHAdd_Click()
    Me.txtQOH.Value = Me.txtQOH.Value + 1
End Sub
```